# Can I recover a Jupyter notebook deleted in GCP Dataproc

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

Hi accidentally deleted a jupyter notebook that I was running in DataProc

I can't see a checkpoints folder in my GCS bucket. Any suggestions of recovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you never saved the checkpoints before or you explicitly deleted from the dataproc web UI, then it's very likely your data won't be able to recovered.

Things you can check to ensure GCS is able to save your checkpoints:

1. Make sure the GCS is set up correctly to save checkpoints, you can check /etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py and make sure `c.GCSContentsManager.bucket_name` is present and set with right bucket. If not present, you should set it and then from dataproc Web UI, Kernel > Restart to restart Jupyter from the Jupyter menu.
2. Make sure your account have admin/write access to your bucket. How - https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/